# 12h cycle AM/PM in Fluid

Tags: date, time, typo3, fluid, tx-news

In TYPO3 I am using the News Extension to create an Event. In my List view I am using the following code snippet to show the End Time of the Event.

`<f:format.date format=" - %H:%M Uhr">{newsItem.eventEnd}</f:format.date>`

Which results in " - 20:00 Uhr" (German Language, hence the "Uhr").

I want a Format that switches that time to " - 08:00 PM" for the English translation, I am assuming that is not possible in Fluid since my searches have no result. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You can put your format into a locallang file. There it's possible to change the format related to the language.

```
<f:format.date format="{f:translate(key:'dateFormat')}">{newsItem.eventEnd}</f:format.date>
```

Comment: When I use `format="{f:translate(key:'dateFormat')}"` it returns the Date in m/d/Y. {f:translate(key:'dateFormat')} returns "%m/%d/%Y" no matter what I write in the locallang. I tried searching for "%m/%d/%Y" in my Project Folder, thinking my locallang's might be overwritten by something, but no.
My locallang.xlf has this in it:
`<trans-unit id="dateFormat">
<source>m/d/Y h:i A</source>
</trans-unit>`

My de.locallang.xlf:
`<trans-unit id="dateFormat">
<source>m/d/Y h:i A</source>
<target>d.m.Y h:i A</target>
</trans-unit>`

Comment: I updated my german Language pack in the TYPO3 backend, also the "target" parameter was missing from my locallang. Ty !

Answer (score 0):

The date format viewhelper uses the same format as the default PHP `date` and `strftime` functions, so anything you can use `%I:%M %p` to get 08:00 PM. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php and http://php.net/strftime for more about this.